# Java Reading Keyboard inputs in XCode

Tags: java, xcode

I'm trying to develop Java programs in XCode and it is pretty much Ok.
However, when I try to read keyboard inputs, nothing seems to work - what I type is not seen... and the program hangs there...

It setup the Xcode environment based on this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmbdOfYNc3g

The following is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class keyBoardRead{
     public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
          InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
          BufferedReader   br = new BufferedReader(r);
          System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
          String name = br.readLine();
          System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
     }
}
```

Could someone advise me, on how to go about it?

Comment: For testing purposes you can run your program from terminal

Comment: Your code style is pretty wacky.

Comment: @Sanjeev: I did test in terminal and it works perfectly fine. I just wonder if there is a way to make it work without leaving the XCode IDE <br>@Brandon: I would very like to learn about the standard coding style. However, I must admit, I'm a Data scientist who works on large time series data and I use different tools (MATLAB, Python, C++, etc) to suit my purpose. Probably, these are having an impact on my style...:)